# How do I reset Xampp's default page?

Tags: laravel, apache, xampp, vhosts, htdocs

I used to be able to go to localhost on my windows PC with xampp running and be shown the /dashboard page which is fine. I think I made a mistake with a Laravel install and now when I go to localhost I get a Laravel landing page.

How can I reset this so it goes back to the default /dashboard page?

I've tried this in http-vhosts.conf but didn't help:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the default it was at before. I can't do a local Wordpress install any more as when I drop the folder in htdocs and navigate in the browser it gives a Laravel 404 error.

Answer (score 2):

In C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf
set

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
```

In C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf
Add below settings

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope this will help